# Java SDK Mac OS X build instructions

Tags: java, macos

Where can I find Java SDK 6 or 7 (Oracle's, not [openJDK](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/11/29/building-the-jdk.html)) build instructions for Mac OS X (lion/leopard)?

Something like [JDK Build instructions v6u23](http://download.java.net/jdk6/6u23/promoted/b05/docs/build/README-builds.html), for the source code available at http://download.java.net/jdk6/source/.

Googling for an hour just gives me how to use java on Mac.

p.s. Source code snapshots repository for JDK 6 and 7 are available at java.net, but [jdk.researcher or jdk.contributor role for jdk project are required to access them](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/idk/archive/2006/09/readonly_subver.html).

Comment: Can you actually get hold of Oracle's non-OpenJDK source code for Java 6 or Java 7??

Comment: you can't? i thought they keep them here http://java.net/projects/jdk6/sources

Comment: http://jdk7.java.net/download.html seems to hosts snapshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, you could never do this on the Mac, because the codebase is not actually the same as the one available for building on Solaris, Linux and Windows (since it requires additional closed source components). This is why people got scared when Apple said they would stop shipping Java with OS X.

However, Apple then announced that they would contribute those necessary packages to Oracle, so Oracle could build the OpenJDK VM for OSX. Additionally, there won't be a Java7 version on OS X, this will be strictly OpenJDK.

You can build that version on OSX. The following provides some instructions as well as a slew of links: http://code.google.com/p/openjdk-osx-build/wiki/DoItYourself

You may also want to look into SoyLatte:
http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/static/soylatte/

Comment: i'd be happy with 'only' getting javac to work. is this maybe possible?

Comment: If you're including Leopard (and I assume Snow Leopard), and Java6 is available on those platforms, why do you need to build the SDK yourself? It's not available on Lion, but that would be a separate question from this.

Comment: Well as I stated, this was never an option for the non-OpenJDK version on the Mac. This was also why the version on OSX continually lagged, because Apple had to build it themselves.

The links above will probably give you the best information (most importantly the ones on SoyLatte, including this one: http://infernus.org/2009/02/building-java-7-on-mac-os-x/).